# 'Failed to find session configuration default' (lightdm.log)

Tags: kubuntu, login, kde, lightdm, ldap

When trying to log onto a Kubuntu 14.04 LTS system. I noticed that all users would pass, when logging in via `ssh`, but graphical login (i.e. LightDM with the KDE greeter) would just be possible for local accounts.

More precise: LDAP users would be authenticated with ease, but then KDE Plasma would not start up. The relevant lines of the log file:

```
# /var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log
DEBUG: Seat: Failed to find session configuration default
DEBUG: Seat: Can't find session 'default'
```

The lines do not show up when local accounts log in.

How to fix this? Explanations?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You probably did not set the `user-session` in LightDM's config file, e.g.

```
# /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
[SeatDefaults]
user-session=plasma-kde
...
```

therefore LightDM looks into the user's `~/.dmrc` file and finds

```
Session=default
```

and hence looks for `/usr/share/xsessions/default.desktop` which is missing.

Comment: Changing `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` did not fix it for me, but modifying `~/.dmrc` did the trick. Isn't `~/.dmrc` prioritary over the `/etc/` configuration?

Answer (score 7):

sure, thread is pretty old - but anyway:
stumbled over this thread, when trying to fix 
lightdm not starting on a bananapi M3 (armbian) 
- solution was to 
apt install lightdm-gtk-greeter 
(which was not pulled in when installing lightdm)
maybe this helps someone :)

Comment: Upgrading linux mint  to  v20 found your solution .
greeter was absent ,  ended up  installing  slick-greeter  as lightdm-gtk-greeter looked not so  slick,   but  anyway ,  thank you  very  much ,  the answer  ended my  frustration.

Comment: thanks for sharing.  I wonder what's the oldest answer from SO that are still actively found and used now... :-)