# "Failed to start session" on login

Tags: 16.04, kubuntu, lightdm, ldap

I have a machine (let's name it `my-machine`), which runs Ubuntu 16.04.

`my-machine` is connected to LDAP, and I use an LDAP account to login to it. With my LDAP account, I use exclusively this machine.

However, today, I used my LDAP account to connect to another machine (let's call it `second-machine`), which runs Kubuntu.

After that, I am not able to login to `my-machine` anymore. The graphical user prompt prints error message `Failed to start session`.

However, when I switch to console, using `ctrl + alt + F1`, I still am able to login successfully.

Now, when listening to file `/var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log` in console, during a graphical login, here are the logs I see:

```
DEBUG: Authenticate result for user myuser: Success
DEBUG: User myuser authorized
DEBUG: Greeter requests default session
DEBUG: Seat seat0: Failed to find session configuration default
DEBUG: Seat seat0: Can't find session 'default'
```

## Question

Why am I not anymore able to GUI-login on my Ubuntu machine?

How can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

*Answering my own question*

It turns out logging into the Kubuntu machine added/modified a `~/.dmrc` file in my LDAP home folder, with the following content:

```
[Desktop]
Session=default
```

This is where the `Can't find session 'default'` log line comes from. Indeed, when taking a look at `/usr/share/xsessions` (as hinted in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/504402/412393)), the only file I find is

```
/usr/share/xsessions/ubuntu.desktop
```

Session `default` does not seem to exist.

Modifying `~/.dmrc` to `Session=ubuntu` fixed the GUI-login.